# How to pass multiple parameters from url in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am newbie. How to pass multiple parameters from URL in codeigniter? 
My function showing ads in a given category

```
    public function show_category($category = false, $subcategory = false, $state = false, $city = false)
{
   // Showing ads...
}
```

I would like my urls to look like this

```
localhost/show_category/category/subcategory/state/city
```

But what if one of the parameters is not given? How to make category not mistaken for a city when I pass only two parameters?

```
localhost/show_category/category/city
```

Comment: In such case, you should use get method to differentiate among parameters

Comment: this is explained here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#class-reference

Comment: @Riosant can you write something more how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering it for SEO purpose, I think it would be safe to leave just the category and the subcategory in the url, and leave the rest as `GET` variable :

```php
public function show_category($category = false, $subcategory = false)
{
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $city = $_GET['city'];
   // Showing ads...
}
```

then you can skip the `category` and `subcategory` url segment, and send the `state` and `city` as query string :

```
localhost/show_category/category/subcategory?state=x&city=y
```

Comment: thanks, it should work.. but how to do routing for this?

Comment: I have sth like that but it doesnt work well `$route['(:any)'] = 'show_category/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'show_category/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/?(:any)'] = 'show_category/$1/$2?city=$3';`